# Conflict between Guava and AndroidX Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I have this `Xamarin.Android C#` project in where I managed to retrieve my data from my Firestore DB to my app against all the odds from one of Firebase support guys who mentioned a few weeks ago because of Xamarin is not officially supported or something like that.

Anyway, all was working perfectly until I needed to use Google Auth which needs `AndroidX` Nuget Package in my project, and seems to exist a well known conflict between `Guava` and `AndroidX` packages.

So, now I'm having this error:

> "Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;"

In my 'FirebaseFirestore GetDataBase()' function.

Code:

```
public FirebaseFirestore GetDataBase()
        {
            var app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
            FirebaseFirestore database;
            if (app == null)
            {
                var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .SetProjectId("project-firebase")
                    .SetApplicationId("project-firebase")
                    .SetApiKey("ZIzaSyAq55czhZRo00c1JKHHtzdNiIX7vIXu5Iz")
                    .SetDatabaseUrl("https://project-firebase.firebaseio.com")
                    .SetStorageBucket("project-firebase.appspot.com")
                    .Build();

                app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context, options);
                database = FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(app);
            }
            else
            {
                database = FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(app);  //-- ERROR HERE!
            }
            return database;                    
        }
```

**I tried** downgrading Guava to 27.1.0.0. but then another really bad, maybe the worst, error shows up:

> "java.exe" exited with code 1.

So I went back to `28.2.0.` Guava version, and long story short I'm stuck.

Could you guys please help me to find a workaround to this?

Comment: This is a known problem,you could read it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/258).

Comment: Thank you @LeoZhu-MSFT but the "solution" in that threat was to downgrade to Guava 27.1.0.0. and as I mentioned that's not an option for me because then Guava start messing with Firebase.Auth and "java.exe" error shows up and is a mess. I might considere avoid using AndroidX. I might try that...

Comment: Ok,If it works,please let me know.

Comment: In my case I implemented AndroidX at the end as a new update, so I already had all the logistic configured with Firebase so the fastest, easiest and (for me) the best solution was to stop using AndroidX and start uninstalling all AndroidX package. (Let me tell you, it was a lot.)

It wasn't easy because even some of the last updates from Guava or Xamarin.Firebase if I recall correctly, depends on AndroidX so I recommend to check that before you update your Nuget packages.

So, long story short, my solution was to stop using AndroidX Nuget package. At least until this issue got fix.

Comment: A 'close enough' issue was fixed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020091/google-firestore-error-getting-database-instance/65083965#65083965)